# How to store and query range data in HBase?

Tags: java, hadoop, solr, hbase

Presently, I am storing Ip mapping data in Solr and it's somewhat like this:

```
Ip-From
Ip-To
Country
```

This forms a single record (document.) When I get a IP as an input, I query Solr to find out the region (country) that it belongs to. The query is straight forward - ip >= ipFrom and ip <= ipTo. The response time is pretty low (good) but still does not meet our requirement. Cannot cache this data in memory as it's very huge.

Hence, I was thinking of using some other storage for this type of data. Is HBase suitable, and if yes, what would be the ideal way of storing and querying such type of data?

Comment: what is the size of your data?

Comment: Around 2 million entries.

Comment: doesn't seems that huge to me, Ip-from and Ip-To are 64 bits long max (IPv6) and imagine the country is around 15 letters. to bytes, this would mean around 143 bytes per entrie, which means 286 MB of data...

Comment: Yes, I guess I can go for caching. I do have some additional information like longitude and latitude, etc. but then even that won't add it up to a very huge number (size.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding : you want to pass Ip (either from or to) and you want to lookup country or region specific to that.

Yes. You an store data in Hbase and query with [filters](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/hbase-the-definitive/9781491905845/ch04.html) if you want to use Hbase as only data store.

In my experience, Solr search is faster than Hbase and can use NRT or Batch indexer(in case you are using CDH)  or some other tool to index Hbase data.

Further more, **Whitefret** raised the concern(which sounds logical to me). along with **ipfrom** ,**ipto** and **country**, if  you storing anything else in solr then hbase can work for you . otherwise there is no need for intermediate storage like Hbase and you need to revisit your solr configuration.

Comment: Yes, will give another try with Solr or may load (of course, after saving it there in a file) that data from HDFS to memory directly. Will update with the results.

Comment: If you are okay, please vote-up "accepted by owner". so that its pointer to other users.